# react, redux, saga - бесконечные запросы

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

Есть приложение на React, у него есть функциональный компонент, в который закидываю в props action, и его вызываю в useEffect:

```
const { Action } = props;
React.useEffect(() => {
    Action()
}, [])
```

Есть reducer, который кладет данные в store, и с помощью saga получаем данные:

```
function* getAction() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(Request.get, 'api/getAction', {}, true)
    if(response !== false) {
      yield put(actions.Action(response.data));
    } else {
      throw new Error()
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    NotifyManager(err)
  }
}
```

Все работает правильно: по redux dev tools, видно что данные попадают в store. Если написать console.log или еще что-то в useEffect то оно выполнится один раз, но сама функция-генератор saga, начинает выполнятся бесконечное количество раз, и запросы бесконечно отправляются, и в store каждую секунду попадают одни и те же данные. С остальными actions и sagas таких проблем нет, все работает корректно. Для создания actions использую redux-act. Если кто-то знает или есть предположения, я очень буду благодарен. Так же если необходима дополнительная информация пишите.

```
export default function* watcher() {
yield takeLatest(actions.getAction, getAction)
}
```

Comment: Как функция генератор `getAction` у Вас вызывается? Я про вотчер, навешенный на нее и таску типа `takeEvery` или `takeLatest`. На первый взгляд сага как сага

Comment: Дополнил. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в action. Возможно этот экшен `yield put(actions.Action(response.data));`  вызывает событие yield takeLatest(actions.getAction, getAction). Проверьте, пожалуйста, возможно один и тот же тип на эти экшены.

Comment: Поставьте как ответ, очень помогли.